# Replace content of a specific column in a CSV with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, csv

I have several CSV log files and want to replace the status codes stored in the 8th column of these log files with a description

The log files looks like this:

```
ip,date,time,zone,cik,accession,extention,code,size,idx,norefer,noagent,find,crawler,browser
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-23,00:00:00,0.0,1238039.0,0001179110-17-009492,calc.xml,301.0,654.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.0,
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-25,00:00:00,0.0,793347.0,0000798086-17-000026,index.htm,200.0,31791.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-28,00:00:00,0.0,918537.0,0001209191-17-041401,index.htm,200.0,9936.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,
```

The result I'm trying to achieve would look like this:

```
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-23,00:00:00,0.0,1238039.0,0001179110-17-009492,calc.xml,MOVED PERMANENTLY,654.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.0,
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-25,00:00:00,0.0,793347.0,0000798086-17-000026,index.htm,OK,31791.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-28,00:00:00,0.0,918537.0,0001209191-17-041401,index.htm,OK,9936.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,
```

My code currently looks like this, but it doesn't access the 8th column like I want it too

```
 sed -r 's/^(([^,]*,){7})/200.0/OK/;s/206.0/PARTIAL CONTENT/;s/301.0/MOVED PERMANENTLY/;s/304.0/NOT MODIFIED/;s/400.0/BAD REQUEST/;s/403.0/FORBIDDEN/;s/404.0/NOT FOUND/;s/429.0/TOO MANY REQUESTS/;s/500.0/INTERNAL SERVER ERROR/;s/502.0/BAD GATEWAY/;s/503.0/SERVICE UNAVAILABLE/;s/504.0/GATEWAY TIMEOUT/'
```

How can I modified my code so that it replaces the codes in the 8th column?

**Edit:** Very clunky solution, but it works:

```
 sed -r 'h; s/^(([^,]*,){7}).*/\1/; x; s/^(([^,]*,){7})//; s/200.0/OK/;s/206.0/PARTIAL CONTENT/;s/301.0/MOVED PERMANENTLY/;s/304.0/NOT MODIFIED/;s/400.0/BAD REQUEST/;s/403.0/FORBIDDEN/;s/404.0/NOT FOUND/;s/429.0/TOO MANY REQUESTS/;s/500.0/INTERNAL SERVER ERROR/;s/502.0/BAD GATEWAY/;s/503.0/SERVICE UNAVAILABLE/;s/504.0/GATEWAY TIMEOUT/; H; x; s/\n//'
```

Comment: Do you REALLY not want the header line printed in the output?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with a lookup table, and with something like `awk` or `perl` rather than `sed`.  For example:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=",";
    codes[200] = "OK";
    codes[206] = "PARTIAL CONTENT";
    codes[301] = "MOVED PERMANENTLY";
    codes[304] = "NOT MODIFIED";
    codes[400] = "BAD REQUEST";
    codes[403] = "FORBIDDEN";
    codes[404] = "NOT FOUND";
    codes[429] = "TOO MANY REQUESTS";
    codes[500] = "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR";
    codes[502] = "BAD GATEWAY";
    codes[503] = "SERVICE UNAVAILABLE";
    codes[504] = "GATEWAY TIMEOUT";
  };
  FNR == 1 { next };   # skip header line
  { c = $8+0; if (c in codes) { $8 = codes[c] } };
  1
' log.csv
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-23,00:00:00,0.0,1238039.0,0001179110-17-009492,calc.xml,MOVED PERMANENTLY,654.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.0,
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-25,00:00:00,0.0,793347.0,0000798086-17-000026,index.htm,OK,31791.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-28,00:00:00,0.0,918537.0,0001209191-17-041401,index.htm,OK,9936.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,
```

The `$8+0` makes awk evaluate the 8th field as a number, which causes it to drop the unnecessary `.0`.   I'm not sure why your log file has a floating point number for HTTP result codes, but if that's what's in the file, it needs to be handled.  You could do that by making the indices include the `.0`, I prefer to use the integer values.

If the code number in field 8 is unknown, it is left unchanged.  Otherwise, it's replaced by the corresponding value in the `codes` array.

---

BTW, the semi-colons at the end of each line are optional in awk, they're only required if you have more than one statement on a line.  I've left them in there so you could squeeze the entire script into one unreadably long line if you wanted to. Some people like to do that. I don't know why.  Masochism, maybe.  I think it's better to save the actual script into a file and run it with `awk -f` or with a `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` line.

---

Also BTW, it's not at all difficult to find files or web pages containing complete HTTP response code tables.  It also wouldn't be difficult to save that into a text file, edit it into a suitable format (e.g. `numeric-code<tab>description`) and have the awk script read that file before any input file(s) and store it in an array, instead of hard-coding the array in the BEGIN block.  This table isn't something that changes often, so it's probably not worth the bother....but is something to keep in mind for other jobs that need a simple lookup table.

---

Finally, here's a perl version.  This one uses the [HTTP::Status](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Status) library module from the [HTTP::Message](https://metacpan.org/release/HTTP-Message) library collection, which already has all the HTTP status codes in it.

```
$ perl -MHTTP::Status -F, -lane '
  next if $. == 1;                # skip header line
  $msg = status_message($F[7]+0); # perl arrays start from 0, not 1
  $F[7] = uc($msg) if $msg;       # uc() to all-caps the msg
  print join(",",@F);
  close(ARGV) if eof' log.csv 
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-23,00:00:00,0.0,1238039.0,0001179110-17-009492,calc.xml,MOVED PERMANENTLY,654.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.0
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-25,00:00:00,0.0,793347.0,0000798086-17-000026,index.htm,OK,31791.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0
101.xx.xxx.xx,2017-06-28,00:00:00,0.0,918537.0,0001209191-17-041401,index.htm,OK,9936.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0
```

As well as not having to "reinvent the wheel", one of the other benefits of using perl instead of awk is that you could use the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module for a proper CSV parser (i.e. one that can handle quotes, and commas embedded inside quoted fields), and to ensure that your output is properly formatted CSV (again, with quotes as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,]*,){7})200\.0/\1OK/;s/206.0/PARTIAL CONTENT/;s/301.0/MOVED PERMANENTLY/;s/304.0/NOT MODIFIED/;s/400.0/BAD REQUEST/;s/403.0/FORBIDDEN/;s/404.0/NOT FOUND/;s/429.0/TOO MANY REQUESTS/;s/500.0/INTERNAL SERVER ERROR/;s/502.0/BAD GATEWAY/;s/503.0/SERVICE UNAVAILABLE/;s/504.0/GATEWAY TIMEOUT/'
```

The only change is from `/200.0/` to `200\.0/\1`, testing for a period `\.` not any character `.` and using a backreference '\1'. Presumably you are confident that none of the other response codes (206.0 up) would occur as text earlier in the line (206.0 could be part of an ip address...)?

It could be done with other tools such as `awk` more elegantly, but I think this does what you want and builds on what you already have.

Comment: I got it working, but I will most certainly look into using awk going forward.